# I'm not getting any data when i'm trying to connect to a site with the proxy

Tags: python, http, server, proxy

I got a homework of trying to do a simple proxy server,i tried to do server that would get some data,so that  i would get the site,when using a normal client i'm getting the data,but when using the proxy from Windows and trying to connect to a site using Chrome i'm getting nothing.

```
import socket, sys
max_conn = 5
buffer_size = 8192

def start():
    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        print ("[*] Socket initialized...")
        s.bind(('localhost', 80))
        s.listen(max_conn)
        print ("[*] Socket binded to port " + str(80) + "...")
    except Exception as e:
        print ("[*] Failed to initialize socket, exiting...")
        sys.exit(2)

    while True:
        try:
            (clientsocket, address) = s.accept()
            print ("Connect")
            data = clientsocket.recv(buffer_size)
            print(data)

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print ("\n[*] KeyboardInterrupt - exiting...")
            sys.exit()
```

I expect the output of the http protocol, but the actual output is nothing.

Comment: What do you mean by a "regular client"? How are you configuring Windows to use the proxy? I ran your code and can see HTTP output using Firefox configured to point to the server with SOCKS5 and SOCKS4.

Comment: Using a socket client in python and using this option http://www.enigmasoftware.com/images/2014/google-chrome-proxy-settings.jpg

Comment: If you click advanced, what does the configuration look like?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/zO89ec7 i changed the port btw

Answer (score 0):

You have to change Windows to use the SOCKS proxy instead of HTTP.

Comment: Which name need to give to the SOCKS proxy and the port is the one i should for the program right?